# Have user add "tags" while adding article with Mongoid & Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Im using Ruby on Rails to allow a user to add a project post much like Stackoverflow. I can do this with the regular MySQL database, but I am unsure as to how it works with Mongoid.

This is how the process works:

1. User writes some details about the project (client, date, description)
2. Add tags like Stackoverflow, where they just simply need to add a space between each one.
3. Submit the post

Now in my model I try to break the tags up into an array (splitting where there is a space) and then saving the tags one after the other. However, the row for the Project and the Tag do not reference one another. The Project tag_ids = [] and the Tag project_ids = []

project.rb model

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
  field :client, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String
  field :url, :type => String
  field :project_date, :type => Date
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  attr_accessor :tag_names
  after_save :assign_tags

  def tag_names
    @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(" ")
  end

  def assign_tags
  @project = self
  @project_id = self.id
    if @tag_names
      self.tag_names = @tag_names.split(/\s+/).map do |name|
        Tag.find_or_create_by(:name => name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

tag.rb model

```
class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type=> String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

Any ideas as to how to add these reference ids? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and the input _form.html.erb has this   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_names %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_names %>
  </div>

Comment: StackOverflow actually uses javascript to split up tags, not sure if they do preprocessing but it would be trivial on the front end.

Comment: Well the problem isn't the breaking up of tags. I can get that. It's having the tag_ids referenced I'm the project and project_ids referenced in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this:

```
t = Tag.find_or_create_by(:name => name)
self.tags << t unless (self.tags.include? t)
```

Comment: I ended up specifying  project_id = self.id and then   :project_ids => [project_id] for the tags. the tags were then given the project_ids and the project automatically added the tag_ids. thanks everyone.

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem and it drives me crazy! Did you found a solution better then assigning the ids directly?

Comment: Can you explain why my answer doesn't work? The << assignment should take care of foreign IDs for you.